# Iterating over NSObject set as a certain type

Tags: swift, casting

I have a function that that receives a `Set<NSObject>` and I need to iterate over the set as a `Set<UITouch>`. How exactly do I test for this and unwrap the set?

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in touches {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the as operator to perform [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338):

```
for touch in touches {
    if let aTouch = touch as? UITouch {
         // do something with aTouch
    } else {
         // touch is not an UITouch
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would use a conditional cast to check each element
for its type. But here, the `touches` parameter is
[*documented*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:)
 as

> A set of `UITouch` instances that represent the touches that are moving
>   during the event represented by *event*.

therefore you can force-cast the entire set:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in touches as! Set<UITouch> {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Note that in Swift 2 the function declaration changed to

```
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

(due to the "light-weight generics" in Objective-C) so that a cast is not needed anymore.

Comment: Exactly, in this case you can "afford" a force-cast. Your code will be safe.